# How to make a command/string run a function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to make commands that will run a certain function however I'm not 100% sure how to do this properly so far I have this which does work however I don't know how to make it better and if I'm being honest I don't know if this is even the proper way to do it.

```
def command1():
    print("This is function for command1")

def command2():
    print("This is function for command1")

prefix = "-" #idk how to use this to be honest
commands = {
    "-command": command1,
    "-command2": command2,
}

msg = input()
if commands[msg]:
    print("command exisits")
    commands[msg]()
```

Comment: Use this instead https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html

Comment: I think this question should belong to code review.  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd suggest the `cmd` module from the standard library if you're building a CLI-like program.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is emulate the standard UNIX-style command line interface stuff.  Check out the `argparse` module, like so:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f", help="Specify the file to work on")

parser.parse_args(sys.argv)

if parser.f:
  work_on_file(parser.f)
```

Something to that effect.  If, on the other hand, you want to use a string description of a method, `eval` is what you want:

```
def method_name():
  print("To be, or not to be...")

string = "method_name()"
eval(string)
string = "method_name"
eval(string)()
```

which prints "To be, or not to be..." twice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to call the function dynamically based on user input. You should be able to accomplish this via the following example:

```
import sys
...
getattr(sys.modules[__name__], commands[msg])()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add to this code line under msg = input()

```
msg = msg + prefix
```